# Store Thousands of TB images on FileSystem or SQL server DB ( one DB or separate DB ?)

Tags: database, image, server

I'm a software developer and developing a web application where a huge no of images shall be saved and can retrieved while viewing the details of specific transactions .Which the best practice and the good decision to take :
1- Store images in Separate Sql server DB.
2- Store images on DB in the same SQL server Db ( could this affect the performance of other tables ?? and what we shall do when the DB size become tens of Terra byte ??)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: 4) Use Amazon S3?

Comment: Any help ????????